# Star Trek Comic story in which convicts are sent to exile in a cluster of planets but with a cruel twist

Tags: star-trek, comics, episode-identification

Publishing date is probably mid-70s but could be before. The Enterprise encounters a system full of inhabitable asteroids which are used as destination for people condemned for crimes by an alien civilization. (Think Australia.) They at first consider it an enlightened and civilized form of punishment. The inmates seem friendly and it looks like they formed a peaceful society in exile, but one of them tells the truth: the planets are geologically unstable, and will explode at a random time. They plan to hijack the Enterprise to save themselves and leave the crew stranded on the doomed planet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's from 1968. (The Brazilian translation I read was published in the mid-70s; also, they printed two or three stories in a single comic.) [Gold Key series, #2](https://www.startrekcomics.info/goldkey.html). Synopsis:

> Kirk is trapped on a doomed asteroid with condemned convicts awaiting
> an unusual execution. Stardate 19:03.4